# Gmail compose section cannot automate using WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, gmail, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I want to automate Gmail compose section. But I can't write email address in To section, Subject section and Body section using WebDriver (java). Can any one help me why this happen? I have used the following code :

```java
driver.findElement(By.id(":lt")).sendKeys("nazifa_cs@yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.id(":lf")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":lf")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id(":lf")).sendKeys("test");
//driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameIndex);

driver.findElement(By.id(":jy")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id(":jy")).sendKeys("test");
```

These code does not work.

Comment: Well I tried out to figure that in Selenium IDE and I was unable to. You will probably have to switch to another provider to test your e-mails...

Comment: I would highly suggest using some sort of API/Library to communicate with 3rd parties as much as possible. Working through an API *should* leave you less vulnerable to changes on their end that break your tests.

Comment: Do you work for the Gmail team at Google? If not, don't try to automate Gmail with WebDriver. If you're trying to learn WebDriver, find a different public site to learn against. If you're just trying to send email, use a mail API (for SMTP) that supports sending email.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test basic scenarios, switching your Gmail to basic HTML mode should make sense. Though, I will still agree with JimEvans that you better not try automating Gmail with WebDriver because of the high amount of randomness in the element attributes that are used on the view.